# Ant compile failed, packages do not exist

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, junit

I'm trying to compile my maven test project in intellij and everytime i compile, i get this error:

```
Buildfile: /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/build.xml

setClassPath:

init:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/build

compile:
     [echo] making directory...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/build
     [echo] classpath------: /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/target/MavenProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
     [echo] compiling...
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/build
    [javac] /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/src/test/java/com/acton/AppTest.java:5: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/src/test/java/com/acton/AppTest.java:6: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/src/test/java/com/acton/AppTest.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class WebDriver
    [javac] location: class com.acton.AppTest
    [javac]         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/src/test/java/com/acton/AppTest.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class FirefoxDriver
    [javac] location: class com.acton.AppTest
    [javac]         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] 4 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/build.xml:78: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is my build.xml file:

```
<!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
<property environment="env"/>

<property name="wspace.jars"            value="${basedir}"/>
<property name="wspace.jars"            value="/Users/un/.m2/repository"/>
<property name="test.dest"              value="${wspace.jars}/build"/>
<property name="test.src"               value="${wspace.jars}/src"/>
<property name="test.reportsDir"        value="/Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/reports"/>



<path id="testcase.path">


    <pathelement location="${test.dest}"/>

    <fileset dir="${wspace.jars}">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

  </path>




<target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
    <path id="classpath_jars">
        <fileset dir="${wspace.jars}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert pathsep=":" 
        property="test.classpath" 
        refid="classpath_jars"/>
</target>

<target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
    </tstamp>
    <condition property="ANT"
               value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"
               else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
        <os family="mac" />
    </condition>

</target>

<!-- all -->
<target name="all">
</target>

<!-- clean -->
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
</target>

<!-- compile -->
<target name="compile" depends="init, clean" > 
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
        <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <echo message="making directory..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath------: ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling..."/>

    <javac 
        debug="true"
        includeantruntime="true"
        destdir="${test.dest}"
        srcdir="${test.src}"
        target="1.5"
        classpath="${test.classpath}"
    />

  </target>

<!-- build -->
<target name="build" depends="init">
</target>




<target name="usage">
    <echo>
        ant run will execute the test
    </echo>
</target>

<path id="test.run">
        <fileset dir="${wspace.jars}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>


<!-- run -->
<target name="run" >  
    <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
                <fileset dir="${test.reportsDir}" includes="**/*"/>
            </delete>
            <java jar="${wspace.jars}" fork="true" spawn="true" />  
            <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="no" printsummary="yes">
                <classpath refid="test.run" />  

              <!--  <classpath ="${test.classpath}"/> -->  
            <batchtest  todir="${test.reportsDir}" fork="true">  
            <fileset dir="${test.dest}">  


 <include name="AppTest.class" />




            </fileset>  
            </batchtest>    
                <formatter type="xml" />  
                <classpath refid="testcase.path" />  
        </junit>
            <junitreport todir="${test.reportsDir}">    
                <fileset dir="${test.reportsDir}">  
                    <include name="TEST-*.xml" />  
                </fileset>  
                <report todir="${test.reportsDir}" />  
            </junitreport>
        </target>
```

Not sure where im doing wrong, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this Maven or Ant? You listed both.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, Selenium is not in your class path, which appears to be exactly `/Users/username/Desktop/workFiles/maven/MavenProject/target/MavenProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

It is surprising that you refer to this as a Maven project, and yet you choose to build it with Ant.  Maven is also a build tool, and I believe IntelliJ can build using Maven if you configure your IntelliJ module the right way.